# How to read a RSS Feed hosted on a domain-restricted GAE app?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication, rss, rss-reader

I've recently created a GAE app for my company.

Access to this app is domain-restricted so only users logged via google from our domain (ie: user@my-company.com) can access the app.

The app generates RSS feeds (ie: my-company.com/rss).

Said feeds cannot be accessed by Feedly since authentication is required.

The goal is to keep the domain restriction, so I guess what I'm looking for is a RSS reader that allows login via a google app account (it'd have to be really easy to use since it is destined to non IT-exprienced users), or better yet, another solution that would allow me to keep Feedly as a Reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not sure if there is any RSS reader that can actually support restricted feeds, you could actually make it work with Feedly something like the following.

In your `app.yaml` you should not require login or anything for the rss URL so it will look something like this:

```
- url: /rss/.*
  script: main.rss
```

And then you should simply generate some unique keys (`uuid` for example) and only if that is on some list responding with the actual feed, otherwise return the access denied.

Your URL will look something like this:

```
http://www.my-company.com/rss/550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000
```

Which is public and not easily guessable. On regular basis you could even reset that key, or have it auto generated per user, which is a better option in my opinion.